# What is a derivative in terms of velocity

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the derivative of a vector valued function $\vec r(t)=f(t)\hat i+g(t)\hat j+h(t)\hat k$ is the velocity of the function at that point, which makes sense, because it is a vector in the direction of the function whose magnitude is the rate of cahnge in arclength of the function.

However, when we talk about a standard function $f(x)$, its derivative is now a scalar which is the rate of change. From what I know derivatives are supposed to represent velocity, but now it is not a vector anymore, so it can not be velocity. How does it relate to velocity?

Comment: It's a velocity in 1-dimensional space (i.e. of a particle moving along the number line according to $f(t)$) instead of 3-dimensional space.

Comment: Derivatives are velocities? That's news to me.

Comment: you dont have to anwer if it looks stupid to you and you dont have anything new to add

Answer (score 1):

Derivatives are by no means velocity - similar to how scalars are by no means position. But if you wish to keep up with the analogy, where 'scalar' means 'position', imagine a number line in which a point moves according to the function $r(t)$, and the position of the point will be the value of $r(t)$. Then the rate of the position at which this point changes on the number line will be called the 'velocity', i.e., $r'(t)$.

Comment: Could it be thought of as a 1dimensional vector?

Comment: Yes, you can. Going left is like a vector pointing in the negative direction and going right is a vector pointing in the positive direction. But be really clear that it is not technically a vector.